# Create a program to ask a number and print all divisors

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, conditional-statements

Below is my code:

```
num= int(input("Please enter number"))
lista= []

for i in range(1,100):
    if num%i ==0:
        lista.append(i)
print(i)
```

But when I run the same, I get the below output:

```
Please enter number24
99

Process finished with exit code 0
```

According to the above logic, my understanding is that the loop will iterate for 99 times because of the range given, and if the remainder is zero for "i", then it should be appended on the list. Not sure where and why my logic is wrong.

Comment: You have an error in your explanation:

Please enter number24 99

could you fix it so we can help you?

Comment: your logic is fine, you're just printing the wrong variable. `i` is 99, but `lista` is what contains the divisors, so you need to print that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are printing just `i`, instead you need to print the complete list at end of loop.
2. You are iterating in the range of `[1, 100)` only for the divisors, however, to find all divisors with this naive approach, you would ideally need to iterate over range of `[1, num)`. For example, 1000 is a divisor for 2000, but your approach would miss the case.
3. Instead of `lista`, you can use `list_divisors` as the variable name as it is more readable.

So your code becomes:

```
num = int(input("Please enter number"))
list_divisors = []

for i in range(1, num):
    if num % i ==0:
        list_divisors.append(i)
print(list_divisors)
```

Comment: It is better is to iterate up to `sqrt(num)` and then work out what the other half of the divisors pairs are.

Comment: @RoachLord True that - this is why I called OP's approach naive. However, this isn't the root cause of OP's issue, which is why I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: @ mu 無 - valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that was so silly thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Aditya Happy to help. Don't to forget to accept and upvote if that worked for you :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work